# Is it possible to break out of a restricted (custom) shell?

Tags: linux, shell, security, go

Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Say I write a shell that takes stdin input, filters this input so let's say only certain commands like

- ls (list contents of binary directory and subdirectory)
- update (git clone)
- build (go build)
- test (go test)
- start (systemctl start this.service only)
- stop (systemctl stop this.service only)
- running (is the binary being executed and with how many GOMAXPROCS?)
- usage (memory, cpu usage)
- gensvc (generate .service file)
- exit (leave shell/logout)

work, you guessed it, I'm trying to give a user only very limited maintenance access over ssh.

Say I'm careful with `\0` (I'd write it in Go anyway using bufio.Scanner)

Is there any way to stop the running shell and execute /bin/sh or similar or any way to get around this shell?

The idea is a user should push their stuff via git to a bare repo, this repo is cloned to the filesystem to a certain directory, then go build is called and the binary is ran with a systemd .service file that is generated previously.

Thinking logically, if the user is only able to write certain strings that are accepted, no there is no way. But maybe you know of one, some ctrl+z witchcraft ;) or whatever.

The only attack surface is the input string or rather bytes. Of course the user could git push a program that builds its own shell or runs certain commands, but that's out of scope (I would remove capabilities with systemd and restrict device access and forbid anything but the connection to the database server, private tmp and all, namespace and subnamespace it TODO)

The only problem I see is git pushing but I'm sure I could work around that in a git only mode argv and adding it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. something like `lish gitmode` and execute stdin commands if they start with git or something like it.

Example:

https://gist.github.com/dalu/ce2ef43a2ef5c390a819

Comment: Don't let them use an editor like `vim`; once they're using `vim`, they can get to the shell, and thence to whatever they like.  You don't mention editing, so you may be fine.  Do pay attention to what might be executed by the build and test commands in particular.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `vim` should be safe if started as `vim -Z`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: interesting; yes, `vim -Z` seems to cut down some of the options.  Original `vi` was not as well contained.  At the very least, you have to be extremely careful with what editors are allowed.

Comment: If security is a concern, perhaps you should consider using a standard restricted shell (e.g. `rbash`) and focus your efforts on configuring that properly.

Comment: If you're allowed to push code that's run with `go test` , that code could certainly spawn anything.

Comment: @isedev I explicitly don't want to provide the user with the ability to run execute binaries in the filesystem.

Comment: @nos indeed, I need to lock down the environment. namespaces, removed capabilities. and finally selinux, apparmor or rbac/grsec. So it's really just for the case where someone somehow acquires the user's private key or credentials to log into the server via ssh or the management console using credentials.

Comment: @dalu a restricted shell allows you to decide **exactly** what a user can execute

Comment: hmm yes @isedev rbash is more generic. I want the user to only be allowed to "write" certain pre-defined commands (or rather accept), which execute pre-defined actions. Thanks for the suggestion tho :).

Comment: here's an answer to the `git push origin master` problem https://gist.github.com/dalu/d890bc70e898ff60dab1 so simple, love Go sometimes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only allowed certain commands, your "shell" will read the command, parse it and then execute it then you should be fine, unless I misunderstood it.

Go "memory" can't be executed, not without you doing some nasty hacks with assembly anyway, so you don't have to worry about shell injection.

Something along these lines should be safe:

```
func getAction() (name string, args []string) {
    // read stdin to get the command of the user
}

func doAction() {
    for {
        action, args := getAction()
        switch action {
            case "update": //let's assume the full command is: update https://repo/path.git
                if len(args) != 1 {
                    //error
                }
                out, err := exec.Command("/usr/bin/git", "clone", "--recursive", args[0]).CombinedOutput()
                // do stuff with out and err
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are implementing the shell yourself and directly executing the commands via `exec()` or implementing them internally, then it is certainly possible to produce a secure restricted shell.  If you are just superficially checking a command line before passing it on to a real shell then there will probably be edge cases you might not expect.

With that said, I'd be a bit concerned about the `test` command you've listed.  Is it intended to run the test suite of a Go package the user uploads?  If so, I wouldn't even try to exploit the restricted shell if I was an attacker: I'd simply upload a package with tests that perform the actions I want.  The same could be said for `build`/`start`.

Comment: yes, git push, clone, build, test, generate service, run service. I need to completely isolate the environment except for tcp outbound and tcp to local database node. When the program is ran I need to make certain nothing can be mounted, and writes only happen to a pre-defined directory (in case of file uploads). Private tmp. All but the base access to /dev nodes forbidden. Thing is, even if someone would manage to run a shell that is available over http, they should not be able to run anything with elevated permissions. I don't know which answer to pick. I'll leave it open, both are good.

Answer (score 1):

Have it reviewed by a pentesting team.

People can be very creative when breaking out a sandbox of any type. Only if you never accept the user's input you can consider yourself rather safe on premises (but here any command is an input) - paper security assumptions are considered a weak to assess the software. They are similar to 'no-bug' assumptions for an algorithm on paper: as soon as you implement it, 99% of time a bug raises